# Should I put basic graphic design skills on my resume?

Tags: resume, skills

I have started using programs like PiktoChart and Canva (a little bit of photoshop) to design infographics for my current internship site. I'm not in the graphic design field, but I think these skills could be useful in the future.

Is it worth it to put them in my resume, even if I don't have tons of experience with them. (also keep in mind that PiktoChart and Canva are meant to be easy to navigate).

Also, how should I phrase it? I was going to say something like, "Graphic design: PiktoChart, Canva, beginner photoshop)

Comment: what kind of jobs you will be applying for?

Answer (score 9):

Your **BASE resume** that no one ever sees but you should include everything you have ever done or accomplished in life. It should include your education, previous jobs, clubs, activities, special skills, anything that might be relevant to a potential employer, including graphic design skills.

When you are looking for a job, you take the BASE resume and you customize it for the potential employer. You leave off graphic design skills for employers were it will not be relevant.

Do not create a single resume and use it as a cookie cutter template, sending the exact same resume to every prospective employer.

Answer (score 1):

If you used it in a professional capacity, then put it on there. Might be a boon in the future, and if pressed at an interview you can give your level of expertise. It shouldn't hurt you unless you specifically apply as a Graphic Artist. Other things, like GUI designer or the like, can use those skills at times. I can't count the number of times I've had to put together a graphic for a site because we needed an icon or whatnot.

Answer (score 1):

Your resume should make it obvious what kind of position you are a fit for by having related skills and experience.  If you list skills and experience that are really not related to the position you are applying for, I've found recruiters tend to be really confused by it, and get the wrong impression of what you're looking for.  Your resume should send a very clear and concise message, like a long form business card.

Therefore, if the positions you're looking to apply to are very much outside graphic design, don't put those skills on.  If you're applying to positions where they might be tangentially related, you might put something on there, but make it not prominently featured.

You might also, however, put samples that include your graphic design work on a website that you provide links to on your resume.  Once you have the recruiter interested enough by the information they get out of your resume to pay you more attention, then they might take a look at your website, and there is the opportunity to convey more about yourself as an individual, and show off any additional skills you might have.